# Обособление оборота с "вопреки"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Заголовок: "***Работаем (,) трудностям вопреки***".
Стоит обособить в данном случае? Вроде, интонационная пауза напрашивается, но сомнения немного терзают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Работаем, трудностям вопреки.** Сравнить: Работаем вопреки трудностям.

Инверсия оборота позволяет его обособить с целью  **выделить, подчеркнуть значимость.**

При отсутствии инверсии нераспространенность оборота препятствует обособлению.